# fpermissive class constructorstack class: fpermissive on constructor

Tags: c++, class, gcc

I keep getting:

```
../src/stack.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
../src/stack.cpp:34:28: error: invalid conversion from ‘stack*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
stack stos1 = new stack(10);
                        ^
../src/wieze-oig.cpp:10:2: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘stack::stack(int)’ [-fpermissive]
stack(const int size){
initializing argument 1 of ‘stack::stack(int)’ [-fpermissive]
```

On this code:

```
class stack
{
    int stacksize;
    stack(const int size)
    {
        this->stacksize = size;
        this->data = new char[stacksize];
        this->ctr = 0;
    }
}
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating an object on this line:

```
stack stos1 = new stack(10);
```

And you're trying to initialize it with a pointer, which can't be done. It looks like you meant to make `stos1` a pointer:

```
stack* stos1 = new stack(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

of course in production code you'd fix it like this:

```
#include <stack>

std::stack<char> stos;
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack